# Compiling my own modules?

Tags: perl

I developed my own module (package) for example `MyUtils.pm`.
That is a file located on same folder than the `main.cgi` that use it. Then I use the module with `use MyModule;`

I think that is a bit slow. Or suppose there's a better way.
Is it possible to "compile the module" and include it in perl core or something like that?

If yes, I think it will load and run "faster".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't worry too much about it. The overhead of loading a Perl module is quite low.

If your application is getting enough traffic that this overhead *does* become significant, it's time to stop using CGI — the overhead of starting the Perl interpreter becomes a problem on its own. Consider switching your site to use something like FastCGI (with [`CGI::Fast`](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Fast/lib/CGI/Fast.pm) or [`Plack::Handler::FCGI`](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack/lib/Plack/Handler/FCGI.pm)), or the [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) Apache module (possibly in conjunction with [`ModPerl::Registry`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/ModPerl/Registry.html) to run CGI scripts directly, or with [`Plack::Handler::Apache2`](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack/lib/Plack/Handler/Apache2.pm)). Any of these will allow multiple consecutive requests to be handled by a single process, bypassing the module loading process entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [B::Bytecode](http://search.cpan.org/~rurban/B-C-1.51/lib/B/Bytecode.pm).

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Compiles a Perl script into a bytecode format that could be loaded
>   later by the ByteLoader module and executed as a regular Perl script.
>   This saves time for the optree parsing and compilation and space for
>   the sourcecode in memory.